# Is there any geographical zone that permits all 802.11 frequencies?

Tags: wifi, openwrt

When I run OpenWRT sometimes I get errors like this,

```
daemon.notice hostapd: Frequency 5720 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x800416b NO-IR RADAR
daemon.err hostapd: Primary frequency not allowed
```

I can change it quite a bit, and it's still not allowed

> daemon.notice hostapd: Frequency 5520 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x30197b NO-IR RADAR

Is there any geographical zone I can put my equipment in to ensure I don't get these errors?

---

*I realize this may be illegal in some jurisdictions however, where I plan to use this for business purposes it is not illegal.*

Comment: These settings exist to make sure the device works according to local laws regarding electronic emissions. Circumventing these settings would violate local laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [this table](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/reference/specifications/access-point-ax411-country-channel-support.html) for 2.4GHz the country with permit most of the channels is Japan. For 5GHz seems like American Samoa, Azerbaijan (and probably other countries) offer most of the channels.

But I recommend you to stay with the bands permitted in your country of residence. Otherwise you can interfere with some government managed bands and expect police to knock on your door.

Comment: Good answer, thanks! That table is a great find.